# EOFException en sockets

Tags: java, socket

tengo un ejercicio simple de sockets en el que el cliente una vez conectado al servidor le envía cadenas de texto y el servidor calcula la longitud de dichas cadenas. El programa debe terminar cuando se introduce un '*', momento en el que el servidor se debe de desconectar.

Todo funciona ok, el cliente se desconecta correctamente pero el servidor, una vez se desconecta me salta una excepcion `java.io.EOFException` que no consigo localizar dónde puede estar el error. Adjunto código del cliente y del servidor:

```java
public class Servidor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket servidor = null;
        Socket clienteConectado = null;
        DataInputStream flujoEntrada = null;
        String readUTF="";
        try {
            servidor = new ServerSocket(6000);
            clienteConectado = servidor.accept();
            flujoEntrada = new DataInputStream(clienteConectado.getInputStream());
            readUTF  = flujoEntrada.readUTF();
            while (!readUTF.equals("*")) {                
                
                System.out.println("Longitud: " + readUTF.length());
                readUTF  = flujoEntrada.readUTF();
            }
         

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            flujoEntrada.close();
            clienteConectado.close();
            servidor.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("SERVIDOR DESCONECTADO");

    }

}

public class Cliente {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket cliente = null;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        DataOutputStream flujoSalida = null; 
        String texto = "";
        boolean redFlag = false;
        try {
            cliente = new Socket("localhost", 6000);
            System.out.println("INTRODUCE CADENAS DE TEXTO");
            flujoSalida = new DataOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
            texto = entrada.nextLine();
            while(!redFlag){
                flujoSalida.writeUTF(texto);
                System.out.println("Introduce otra cadena");
                texto = entrada.nextLine();
                if(texto.equals("*")){
                    redFlag = true;
                }
            }
            
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Cliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        try {
            flujoSalida.close();
            cliente.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Cliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        System.out.println("CLIENTE DESONECTADO");
        
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error probablemente puede ser que estás intentando leer más datos del flujo de entrada una vez que el cliente se ha desconectado, lo que resulta en una excepción `java.io.EOFException` (End of File Exception).

Prueba a cambiar tu ciclo while por esto:

```
while (true) {
    readUTF = flujoEntrada.readUTF();
            
    if (readUTF.equals("*")) {
        break; // Salir del ciclo si se recibe '*'
    }
            
    System.out.println("Longitud: " + readUTF.length());
}
```

**EDIT**

Clase Servidor completa:

```
public class Servidor {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket servidor = null;
        Socket clienteConectado = null;
        DataInputStream flujoEntrada = null;
        String readUTF="";
        try {
            servidor = new ServerSocket(6000);
            clienteConectado = servidor.accept();
            flujoEntrada = new DataInputStream(clienteConectado.getInputStream());
            while (true) {
                readUTF  = flujoEntrada.readUTF();
                if (readUTF.equals("*")) {
                    break; // Salir del bucle si el cliente envía '*'
                }
                System.out.println("Longitud: " + readUTF.length());
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                flujoEntrada.close();
                clienteConectado.close();
                servidor.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Servidor.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("SERVIDOR DESCONECTADO");
        }
    }
}
```

Clase Cliente completa:

```
public class Cliente {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket cliente = null;
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        DataOutputStream flujoSalida = null;
        String texto = "";
        try {
            cliente = new Socket("localhost", 6000);
            System.out.println("INTRODUCE CADENAS DE TEXTO");
            flujoSalida = new DataOutputStream(cliente.getOutputStream());
            while (true) {
                texto = entrada.nextLine();
                flujoSalida.writeUTF(texto);
                if (texto.equals("*")) {
                    break; // Salir del bucle si el usuario envía '*'
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Cliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } finally {
            try {
                flujoSalida.close();
                cliente.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Cliente.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            System.out.println("CLIENTE DESCONECTADO");
        }
    }
}
```

Tanto el cliente como el servidor estarán sincronizados para terminar sus operaciones cuando se envíe el carácter '*'. Esto debería evitar la excepción `EOFException` y permitir una desconexión adecuada entre ambos.

Comment: Sigue saltándome el error.java.io.EOFException
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUnsignedShort(DataInputStream.java:340)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:589)
 at java.io.DataInputStream.readUTF(DataInputStream.java:564)
 at clienteservidoractividad1.Servidor.main(Servidor.java:24)

Comment: en la clase Cliente, en el while tambien has puesto el break?

Comment: He añadido como quedarían las clases Servidor y Cliente